# Wrapping a Disc around a Sphere

Tags: cinema-4d

Been trying to figure this out... I'm modelling a robot and I want to wrap it's face display (disc) around he's head (sphere). I've tried the warp and spline warp tool but that's not showing any result. Any ideas or tips?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can wrap a disc around the majority of a sphere without distorting the disc's edges. You should be able to use two bend modifiers(on for each axis) using the same bend angle/amount to match the sphere's curvature. It will look more like a Kippah.

Comment: To make it wrap you need to make it editable. Press C on keyboard. Make a copy before.